# Отправка действия от сервера [nodejs, socket.io]

Tags: node.js, socket.io, javascript

Приветствую Всех!

Возникла задача, в интервале через каждые 5 минут отсылать, всем кто есть на страницу определенное действие, каким образом отослать?

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler),
io = require('socket.io').listen(app),
static = require('node-static'); // for serving files

var fileServer = new static.Server('./');

// Users
var clients = 0;

app.listen(8080);

function handler (request, response) {

    request.addListener('end', function () {
    fileServer.serve(request, response);
    });
}

setInterval(function(){ io.sockets.emit('timer_sec', {'text':'Таймер прошел!'}) },         10000);

io.set('log level', 1);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    ++clients;

    socket.on('mousemove', function (data) {
    socket.broadcast.emit('moving', data);
});

socket.on('disconnect', function () {
    —clients;
});
});
```

Comment: Быть может я не верно понял вопрос, но - в чем сложности?

Comment: Серверная часть начинает работу, когда человек подсоединяется socket.io.connect, т.е. для всех 5 минут буду в разное время.

А нужно не важно. человек находится 2 минуты на странице.. а если таймер уже был до него 3 минуты, то и ему чтобы выдалось.

Comment: Если для всех 5 минут разные, то для каждого клиента нужен свой таймер. Думаю вы и сами это понимаете, но думали о том, что существует какая-то великая магия, о которой вы не знали :)

И еще, если вы побаиваетесь - сами по себе таймеры не приведут к проблемам производительности.

Тем не менее - для более точного ответа опишите, пожалуйста, более подробно - что именно и как вы собираетесь делать

Comment: Нет, 5 минут должны идти в интервале, не важно зашел человек 4 минуты назад, 5 минут назад или 30 секунд назад - если таймер общий прошел, сделать это.

Comment: 5 минут для всех одни. Один таймер для всех

Comment: Определил таким образом, что захожу с Хрома(2 окна).

Начало первый раз 10 секунд проходит. Я жду ещё секунды 3.
Захожу через второе окно, а оно срабатывает через 10 секунд.
А первое окно, как и положено раньше. Т.е. срабатывает таймер у них в разное время.

Comment: На будущее - не агритесь на тех, кто вам пытается помочь, вот, например я, делаю это в первый и последний раз.

Я бы, конечно, мог запостить тест под phantom.js, запостить, выложить вывод, но не в этот раз

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну тогда `setInterval(function(){ io.sockets.emit('e', {...}) },5*60*1000)`, разве не очевидно

Comment: получается использовать данную функцию раньше, чем идет io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {}); - меня это интересовало!

Comment: @V_Tjuryakin, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Кстати - раз вы не знали этого, значит вам определенно не помешало-бы почитать доки, вики и посмотреть несколько исходников.

Comment: Я не нажал по одной причине, что я задал вопрос, но Вы подумали, что я утверждаю и не опровергли, так-что сам ответил себе на вопрос ;)

Comment: Так вы вопрос не совсем грамотно сформулировали, винить в этом можете только самого себя

Comment: К сожалению Ваш метод не работает. Поставил для примера на 10 секунд. Проходит 5 секунд - перезагружаю страницу, должно вывести уведомление через 5 секунд, т.к. 5 уже прошло, а он заново считает 10 секунд.

Comment: код свой выкладывайте, не работает или не правильно работает ваш код, а не мой.

Только помогать вам уже буду не я :)

Comment: Вам самим не смешно? в Server.js (node) все подключено и сокеты работают. А что выкладывать ваш интервал и прием по socket.on?

Это в Server.js
setInterval(function(){ io.sockets.emit('timer_sec', {'text': 'Прошло 10 секунд'}) }, 10000);

Это в Client.js
socket.on('timer_sec', function(data) {
     alert(data.text);
});

Comment: А каким образом вы определили что "оно заново считает"?

У меня есть подозрения что вы просто не учитывали время на подключение и у вас просто сложилось такое впечатление, попробуйте в нескольких браузерах и вы увидите что все работает.

PS: если вас просят выложить код - просто сделайте это, то, что сокеты работают, я и так понял.

PPS: от нефиг делать написал тест, посмотрел, все прекрасно работает, кривое тестирование и неправильные выводы не моя проблема

Comment: @V_Tjuryakin, просто покажите кусок кода, в который вы воткнули  `setInterval`. От ошибок никто не застрахован.